# Laravel Android Chat with firebase or socket.io

Tags: android, laravel, sockets, event-handling, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a chat app which has Laravel as the backend. This is an app where a user sends a question and the response is not always in real time.

Here is flow on how it works.

1. App user types a message and hits on send. ( Using Retrofit calls to
   Post messages)
2. The send is Post request to Laravel which sends back an acknowledgment message.
3. The backend then works on the message and then sends back a response later.

The third step is where I am confused. This is not a push notification, but a chat response. How do I trigger it so that the App user would get it?

How do I do a Post request from Laravel and how do I handle it on the Android App side?

Almost all the examples that I have seen around are one to one or many to many chats.

Can anyone help me on how I should go ahead? Should I use Laravel Events or Firebase push notifications or Laravel with Socket.io and Redis?

Any pointers on what would be the best solution would be great.

Comment: Your example is one-to-one, so if you already know how it works for 1-1 then it's the same; Firebase does make things easier with pre-made SDK & real-time updates but if that's not an issue for you, You may use pulling in your android app; e.g: post msg -> get reponse with msg id -> store in db -> call api to get messages > msg_id ..etc

Comment: My question is how do I send a chat message back to user without kind of having any push notification? or is it that the it is same as push notification?

Comment: Notifications are just a tool to display the messages in a certain way (in Drawer), So yes you may use the same technique that is used to send a notification to single device to accomplish your task. You would have an android service that sets in the background waiting for messages whether you display these as a notification or not is up to you, You may store in local db then display a completely different notification (You're pushing data what you do with it is up to you)